# WSO2 ESB HTTPS Endpoint, call mediator - But a callback is not registered ( anymore) to process this response error

Tags: wso2, esb, mediator, cal

While using Call mediator and Send Mediator (calling HTTPS endpoint with username token by using policy at the endpoint)

Getting the following error :

```
[2015-01-03 03:38:23,058] DEBUG - SynapseCallbackReceiver Callback removed for request message id :
urn:uuid:160c12bd-1286-4ef0-873e-93777380a4a2. Pending callbacks count : 1
[2015-01-03 03:38:23,061] DEBUG - TargetHandler http-outgoing-19: Closed
[2015-01-03 03:38:23,065] DEBUG - TargetHandler http-outgoing-19: Keep-Alive Connection closed
[2015-01-03 03:38:23,064]  WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the reques
t with message Id : urn:uuid:160c12bd-1286-4ef0-873e-93777380a4a2 But a callback is not registered (
anymore) to process this response
[2015-01-03 03:38:23,067] DEBUG - LoggingNHttpClientConnection http-outgoing-19: Shutdown connection

[2015-01-03 03:38:51,472] DEBUG - access - 68.232.203.67 - - [03/Jan/2015:03:38:51 +0530] "POST /Ser
vice.asmx HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO"
[2015-01-03 03:38:51,476] DEBUG - access - 68.232.203.67  - [03/Jan/2015:03:38:51 +0530] "- - " 200
```

I can see the expected response on the console WIRE>> 
but getting this error and the response is not being correlated

please let me know if anyone has faced this issue earlier and how to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Reason might be, your service endpoint  takes much time to respond. Increase the endpoint timeout value in the endpoint configuration and  synapse.global_timeout_interval value in synapse properties file.

Comment: Hi Ratha , I had increased the property in the synapse properties file as mentioned but no luck . getting the same error .

Comment: Did you find any resolution on this? I'm facing similar issue and I can clearly see that the request is reaching the backend and the backend sends the response, but still I see timeout.. no point in increasing the timeout